# CLT infinite mean

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

I am trying to see if we can construct $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$, a sequence of i.i.d random variables such that $E|X_n|=\infty$ while $n^{-1/2}(X_1+...+X_n)$ converges in distribution goes to a $N(0,1)$ random variable. I tried using
$$ n^{1/2}(1/n(X_1+..+X_n))$$ and using SLLN on the inside but then the limit would vanish. Is it even possible to construct such a sequence?

Comment: Why should the SLLN apply? Even before considering the issue of an infinite second moment.

Comment: SLLN is the only thing applicable when we have infinite absolute moments

Comment: Mathematically, what do you mean by "$n^{-1/2}(X_1+...+X_n)$ still goes to normal"?

Comment: Yes my bad, it is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. For the CLT, we need to have almost two finite absolute moments and if the first absolute moment is infinite, so are all higher order moments (this follows from [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Probability_measure)). Hence, the CLT does not hold.

Comment: Why must the CLT hold at all? we are constructing the random variables and so we have full control over it. CLT is more universal and so is too strong to be the only thing this  hinges on.

Comment: @user593295 The CLT does not have to hold. The iid random variables have to belong to the domain of attraction of a normal law for the CLT to hold and not all iid random variables belong to the domain of attraction of a normal law.